# Killing a process stored in Mutex<Option<Child>>

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How to make the following code work?

```
let mut process_guard: MutexGuard<Option<std::process::Child>> = process.lock().unwrap();
if let Some(child) = *process_guard {
    child.kill();
    *process_guard = None;
}
```

Solution:

```
if let Some(mut child) = (*process_guard).take() {
    child.kill();
}
```